# Django: how to change the value of a field one changing another?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have 2 fields in a model I need that when I change the value of a field to calculate the other

Example:

```html
    Date_mission1_equipe=models.DateField (null=True,blank=True,max_length=200)
Date_mission2_equipe=models.DateField (null=True,blank=True,max_length=200)
```

for example if i choose 01/01/2019 for Date_mission1_equipe automatically Date_mission2_equipe should be 02/01/2019

Answer (score 4):

There are few ways to handle this. You could override the model `save` method. Or perhaps the cleanest is to use a `pre_save` signal, as shown below.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

def change_date(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    my_object = MyModel.objects.get(id=instance.id)
    if instance.Date_mission1_equipe:
        a.Date_mission2_equipe = ...

pre_save.connect(change_date, sender=MyModel)
```

Comment: should I add this to the model or to the view ?

Comment: I'm not actually sure if it matters technically where to put this. But for neatness I'd probably just stick this code near the relevant model. The [django signal documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) can tell you more.

Comment: DO NOT use signals. You only use those as a last resort. Like when dealing with a 3rd party app you did not write.

Answer (score 2):

It is often recommended not to store calculated values like this in the database. Instead, just perform the calcaultion when you will need it.

```
from datetime import timedelta

class Mission(models.Model):
    date_mission1_equipe = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def date_mission2_equipe(self):
        return self.date_mission1_equipe + timedelta(days=1)
```

You can now do something like this:

```
first_mission = Mission.objects.get(id=1)
first_mission.date_mission1_equipe
<01/01/2019>
first_mission.date_mission2_equipe
<02/01/2019>
```

That's just an example. The date would probably need to be formatted for your needs, and will not automatically output in the format I put above.

Also, you do not need max_length on a DateField. It makes no sense for this field type.

Comment: what if I wanna call it in a form?